# How to map property to Integer Mapstruct in Java

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I'm having a problem with a mapstruct mapper. When running mvn clean install (or mvn clean compile), I get these errors:

```
[ERROR] /mapper/EntityMapper.java:[28,7] Can't map property "java.util.List<com.socomec.tseselector.model.Source> architecture.sources
" to "java.lang.Integer architecture.sources". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "java.lang.Integer map(java.util.List<com.socomec.tseselector.model.Source> value)".
[ERROR] /mapper/command/TSEProjectCommandMapper.java:[21,16] Can't map property "java.lang.Integer architecture.loads" to "java.util.List<com.socomec.tseselector.model.Load> architecture.loads". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "java.util.List<com.socomec.tseselector.model.Load> map(java.lang.Integer value)".
```

The problem is that I have no idea where mapstruct is getting this "java.lang.Integer architecture.loads" from.
I don't understand where this Integer is coming from, as you can see in my code there is no Integer. Also up until now I never ran into this error while using similar mapper.

Here is my entity Architecture :

```
public class Architecture {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String imagePath;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="tse_architectures_loads",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(table = "tse_architecture", name = "architecture_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(table = "tse_load", name = "load_id")}
    )
    private List<Load> loads;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="tse_architectures_sources",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(table = "tse_architecture", name = "architecture_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(table = "tse_source", name = "source_id")}
    )
    private List<Source> sources;

    private String techno;

    public Architecture() {
        this.loads = new ArrayList<>();
        this.sources = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

The DTO

```
public class ArchitectureDto {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String imagePath;
    private List<LoadDto> loadDtos;
    private List<SourceDto> sourceDtos;
    private String techno;

    public ArchitectureDto() {
        this.loadDtos = new ArrayList<>();
        this.sourceDtos = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

My mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ArchitectureMapper extends EntityMapper<ArchitectureDto, Architecture> {

    @Mapping(source = "loads", target = "loadDtos")
    @Mapping(source = "sources", target = "sourceDtos")
    ArchitectureDto toDto(Architecture architecture);
}
```

Entity Mapper:

```
public interface EntityMapper<D, E> {

    /**
     * Map a DTO to an Entity
     *
     * @param dto the dto to map
     * @return an Entity
     */
    E toEntity(D dto);

    /**
     * Map an Entity to a DTO
     *
     * @param entity to map to a DTO
     * @return a DTO
     */
    D toDto(E entity);

    /**
     * Map a List of DTOs to a List of Entities
     *
     * @param dtoList the list to map
     * @return a list of Entities
     */
    List<E> toEntity(List<D> dtoList);

    /**
     * Map a list of Entities to a list of DTOs
     *
     * @param entityList the list to map
     * @return a list of DTOs
     */
    List<D> toDto(List<E> entityList);
}
```

Looking through the documentation and other questions about mapstruct here, I have not been able to find a solution so far.

I'm addind my load and source classes
Load:

```
public class Load {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String unity;
    private Long sourcePriority1;
    private Long SourcePriority2;
    private Long SourcePriority3;
    private Long kvaValue;
    private Long kwValue;
    private Long pfValue;
    private Long aValue;
    private Long iccValue;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "loads")
    private List<TSEProject> tseProjects;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "loadList")
    private List<Architecture> architectures;

    public Load() {
        this.architectures = new ArrayList<>();
        this.tseProjects = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Source:

```
public class Source {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String unity;
    private Long quantity;
    private Long kvaValue;
    private Long kwValue;
    private Long pfValue;
    private Long aValue;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "sources")
    private List<TSEProject> tseProjects;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "sourceList")
    private List<Architecture> architectures;

    public Source() {
        this.architectures = new ArrayList<>();
        this.tseProjects = new ArrayList<>();
    }

}
```

and the DTOs

```
@Data
public class LoadDto {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String unity;
    private Long sourcePriority1;
    private Long SourcePriority2;
    private Long SourcePriority3;
    private Long kvaValue;
    private Long kwValue;
    private Long pfValue;
    private Long aValue;
    private Long iccValue;
    private List<Long> tseProjectsId;

    public LoadDto() {
        this.tseProjectsId = new ArrayList<>();
    }

}
```

```
@Data
public class SourceDto {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String unity;
    private Long quantity;
    private Long kvaValue;
    private Long kwValue;
    private Long pfValue;
    private Long aValue;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are using up-to-date / the right versions of your entity and DTO classes? MapStruct seems to think that the field `sources` in the DTO is a `java.lang.Integer` but that doesn't correspond with the source of `ArchitectureDto`. Are there getter and setter methods in your DTO? (that you left out in the code above?)

Comment: I have indeed left out the getter and setter. I'm using Lombok to generate getter and setter with @Data.

Comment: As far as I'm aware the field architecture.loads has never been an Integer.
If I am not using an up-to-date version, how would I go about fixing that?

Answer (score -2):

I guess you need to troubleshoot a bit more.. Try to aid MapStruct and define an additional mapping method like this:

```java
Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ArchitectureMapper extends EntityMapper<ArchitectureDto, Architecture> {

    @Mapping(source = "loads", target = "loadDtos")
    @Mapping(source = "sources", target = "sourceDtos")
    ArchitectureDto toDto(Architecture architecture);

    // first try with all properties ignored
    // @Mapping( target = "id", ignore = true ) etc.
    SourceDto toDto(Source source);

    // first try with all properties ignored
    // @Mapping( target = "id", ignore = true ) etc.
    LoadDto toDto(Load load);

}
```

The problem is that MapStruct tries to map these objects automatically based on property names. If it somewhere discovers the same name it tries to do type conversion or to use existing mapping methods to do its job. It even tries 2 steps (so conversion and then a method), which sometimes leads to these results.

You could provide some of the mappings MapStruct tries to generate itself and then again ignore all properties like indicated in the example above. One by one remove the ignore lines and see when MapStruct starts to complain.

If its again an object graph, you could apply a similar strategy.

It's a bit tedious debugging like this, but probably deep down in your object graphs you discover the problem. You could then remove all signatures again, except the one that solved your problem, making maximum use of code generation.